# echo result once if same in select box

Tags: php

I have 'city' field in database which contains postal code and city name like this: '12345 City'
Now  I need to get just those cities and populate a select field. With code below i get duplicate cities (if there is '12345 Chicago' and '54321 Chicago' I get two Chicago options), how to do something like mysql group by or distinct in php?

```
while ($re = mysql_fetch_assoc($rez))
  {
    $city= $re["city"];
    $city= preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "", $city);
    $city= trim($city);

     if ($city==""){echo "";}
     else if ($_SESSION['sess']==$city){
      echo "<option value={$_SESSION['sess']} selected=selected>{$_SESSION['sess']}</option>";
        }
     else echo "<option value=$city>$city</option>";
  }
```

Comment: Why even do it in PHP and not in your query directly?

Comment: because results are not same as i said. in same field there is city and postal code that can be different

Comment: So in your case which value of Chicago should be considered? 54321 or 12345?

Comment: i need just chicago, not the postal codes. with preg_replace and trim i removed them but $city still echoes chicago twice

Comment: @svemirac This is a bad design (what if you have to change a city's name - you will need to check each row and change multiple entries), also I believe you should be able to use something like [`substring`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

Comment: you can still do it in mysql, just remove digits in query: `select distinct REPLACE(column_name,'[0-9]+','') as city`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$city_array = array();
while ($re = mysql_fetch_assoc($rez))
  {
    $city= $re["city"];
    $city= preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "", $city);
    $city= trim($city);

    $city_array[] = $city;
  }
$city_array = array_unique($city_array);
```

then run the foreach loop for `$city_array`

Answer (score 0):

You can store `$city` as key in an array. Since keys in an array are unique you will not get any duplicate values.

```
$ar = array();
while($re = mysql_fetch_assoc($rez)) {
    $city= $re["city"];
    $city= preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "", $city);
    $city= trim($city);

    $ar[$city]=0;
}
```

Then you can use foreach loop to iterate through the key values.

```
foreach($ar as $key =>$value) {
    if($key == "") {
        echo "";
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['sess']==$key){
        echo "<option value={$_SESSION['sess']} selected=selected>{$_SESSION['sess']}</option>";
    }
    else {
        else echo "<option value=$key>$key</option>";
    }
}
```